# ReactJs AdminLTE Dashboard

Tags: reactjs, adminlte

I am new in ReactJS. I want to use ReactJS-AdminLTE in my project. Can anybody tell how to use it with step by step process.

Steps I followed

1) I set Reactjs environment using https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/ tutorial

2) Then I install ReactJS-AdminLTE using command **npm install adminlte-reactjs**

My webpack.config file is

```
var path=require('path');
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "./"),
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import reactjsAdminlte from 'adminlte-reactjs';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {

      return (

            <Box 
    width = 3 
    border = true
    content = 'The body of the box'
    theme = 'box-primary'
    title = 'Collapsable'
    collapsed = true
    boxTools = ['collapse']
/>


      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "app"></div>
      <script src = "index.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

But result is not displaing.

Comment: You start first. What have you tried, and what are the problems you experienced?

Comment: @lux I edited question. I added what I had done.

Comment: @user3479979 I am wonder you didn't get answer yet 

Comment: @user3479979 Can you show us the `main.js`? It get's mentioned in the setup tutorial you have followed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using ReactDOM to render your app component to the HTML?

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```